# Render Partial in WebPages without using MVC

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-2

I'm using Razor with WebPages but without MVC. I like the simplicity with this so I'm not interested in using MVC at this point. However I would like to be able to render a partial into my page. Like a menu, a footer, etc.

With MVC you can to this:
@{ Html.RenderPartial("Footer", Model);}

I would like to do something similar:
@{ Html.RenderPartial("footer.cshtml"); }

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take a look at this link http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/151/Extending-ASP.NET-Web-Pages-Create-Your-Own-Helpers

Hope this will help you

also try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @RenderPage("/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
    <h1>Index Page Content</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the main page.</p>
    @RenderPage("/Shared/_Footer.cshtml")
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `@RenderPage` works exactly like I wanted. The `@helper` (from the tutorial) is also very useful for me. Many thanx!

Comment: @engineer.oop the link is broken, can you please write here the essence of mikesdotnetting's solution?